# Dividing formatted string into smaller strings

Tags: c++, string, text-files

I store list of my students in a text file. Every Student's primary data is stored in one line and list of his classes as second line, where classes are separated by `','`. It goes like `Mathematics,Linear Algebra,Physical Education Adv, Optics,`. If i read this to one string, how can i divide it, so temp1 will get Mathematics, temp2 Linear Algera and so on...?

Comment: Here you have explanation how to do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Comment: Thank you, this link is also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **strtok** function - Use this page for reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Though it might look difficult to use at first, but it's quite efficient

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a robust ready-to-go function that works with std::string and std::vector:

```
using namespace std;
vector<string> splitString(const string &str, const string &delim)
{
    size_t start = 0, delimPos = 0;
    vector<string> result;
    do
    {
        delimPos = str.find(delim, start);
        result.push_back(string(str, start, delimPos-start));
        start = delimPos + delim.length();
    } while(delimPos != string::npos);
    return result;
}
```

I actually pulled this out of my snipped library ;)